# asp.net MVC5: How to get all users and user's role from AspnetUser table by linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get all Users and User's Roles by Linq.
The entities is from ASP.NET MVC identity Framework.

My code:

```
var userList = db.Users
                .Include("Roles")
                .ToList();
```

My entities:
[image]

The result i have for the **Roles** table is "RoleId, UserId" only
. I want to get the Roles which added for each users.

How i can do it?

Thank you.

**UPDATE ANSWERS:**

```
var userList = new List<ManagerUserViewModel>();
            foreach (var user in db.Users.ToList())
            {
                var userRolesId = user.Roles.Select(m => m.RoleId).ToList();
                var model = new ManagerUserViewModel()
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    Email = user.Email,
                    UserInfo = user.UserInfo,
                    Roles = db.Roles.Where(r => userRolesId.Contains(r.Id))
                                    .ToList()
                };
                userList.Add(model);
            }
```

Comment: Could you show us your `User` and `Role` entities?

Comment: i have attach a image link, please see the entities there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you think this is sufficient:

```
// Dummy role name
var name = "Admin";

var rm = new RoleManager<Role>(new RoleStore<Role>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

// Get the role you need (Admin role in this case)
var r = rm.FindByName(name);

// All the user ids that have this role
var userIds = r.Users.Select(u => u.UserId);

// Get all user objects
var users = Db.Users.Where(u => userIds.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();
```